# Referencing an object's function from another function using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS object in my code:

```
var myLibrary = {
  name: "John",

  // Functions
  func1: function() {
    alert(this.name);
  },
  func2: function() {
    this.func1();
  },

  // On DOM loaded
  onDOMLoaded: function() {
    this.func1();
    this.func2();
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myLibrary.onDOMLoaded);
```

When I reference this code using a script tag, I get the following error (in reference to the call in `func2`):

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.func1 is not a function
```

This is especially weird because if I call the functions from within the DOM, they work perfectly. For example:

```
<button onclick="myLibrary.func1()">Func 1</button>
<button onclick="myLibrary.func2()">Func 2</button>
```

Clicking on the buttons does exactly what I want them to. What am I doing wrong here? And how can I fix this issue? Thanks for any help!

A demo can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/gLxvsze0/

Comment: Where in the document are you inserting the `script` element that references the external library?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Please check the demo link

Comment: That doesn't answer the question I'm asking you. In a Fiddle, you hook up external references differently than you do in actual code. Please just tell us where in the HTML document you've included the `script` element that references your library.

Comment: `myLibrary.onDOMLoaded.bind(myLibrary)`

Comment: In HTML event handlers, `this` refers to the HTML element that received the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is JS.

When you call `myLibrary.func1()` the function will be called with `myLibrary` context. But when you call just `func1` (ie `func1 = myLibrary.func1; func1()`) this will be called with global `Window` context.

To solve your problem, you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method, that creates new function linked with provided context:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myLibrary.onDOMLoaded.bind(myLibrary));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution to the context issue is...

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => { myLibrary.onDOMLoaded(); });
```